# BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF and overloaded relational operators

Tags: c++, boost, types, operator-overloading, typedef

I'm using BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF to define strong types from POD types. For example, I want to define a new type from `int`. However if I try to compare my new type to something that's not `int` (e.g. `unsigned int`, `size_t`), I get "Use of overloaded operator '<' is ambiguous" compiler errors.

For example:

```
#include <boost/serialization/strong_typedef.hpp>

BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF( int, Foo );

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Foo f( 10 );

    unsigned int j = 11;
    bool result = j < f;    // Error

    size_t s = 100;
    result = s < f;         // Error

    int h = 101;
    result =  h < f;        // ok

    return 0;
}
```

I can fix these errors by implementing the specific relational operators for the specific types. e.g.:

```
bool operator<(const size_t& y, const Foo& x) {
    return y < x.t;
}
```

Since BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF provides conversion operators from `Foo` to `int`, I would have expected `(unsigned int) < (Foo)` to compile down to the same thing as `(unsigned int) < (int)`, but I guess not.

My question is: Is there any way to avoid implementing every operator for every type I want to compare to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF provides conversion operators from `Foo` to `int`, I would have expected `(unsigned int) < (Foo)` to compile down to the same thing as `(unsigned int) < (int)`, but I guess not.

The `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` macro defines a `struct Foo` that inherits from a bunch of different operator classes, one of which will define:

```
friend bool operator<(const int&, const Foo&); //(1)
```

And of course there's all of the builtins that compare integers:

```
bool operator<(T, U); // (2), implicit
```

For all integral types, `I`, we have several viable candidates for `I{} < Foo{}`. We could convert `I` to `int` and call `(1)`, or we could convert `Foo` to `int` and call `(2)`. Depending on `I`, the result is:

- `I` is `int`: `(1)` is an exact match, and all the builtin operators involve a conversion, so `(1)` is unambiguously preferred.
- `I` has *lower* rank than `int` (e.g. `char`): integral promotion (up to `int`) has better rank than a conversion (`Foo` to `int`), so `(1)` is unambiguously preferred.
- `I` has *higher* rank than `int` (e.g. the `size_t` and `unsigned int` in your example): `(1)` now involves an integer conversion (`size_t` to `int` is not a promotion), and integer conversions have rank Conversion, the same rank as a user-defined conversion. So both `(1)` and `(2)` would have one Exact Match and one Conversion. Since neither is better than the other, it's ambiguous.

> My question is: Is there any way to avoid implementing every operator for every type I want to compare to?

No there isn't. However, you can implement each operator for every type in just one go with templates. For instance, we can resolve all the ambiguities of `<` with:

```
template <typename T>
bool operator<(const T& t, const Foo& f)
{
    return t < static_cast<int>(f);
}
```

For integral types with rank equal to `int`, `(1)` would still be preferred. But for all other integral types, the template would be an exact match whereas the builtins and `(1)` involve some conversion sequence, so this would be preferred - which would forward along to an ambiguous builtin.

Comment: Very informative answer, thanks. Is there a reason to prefer static_cast<int> in the template function over accessing Foo's t member variable directly?